# What is the recommended way to package a Django project? Django package with multiple apps or multiple Django packages?

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I am working on a Django project that is separated into 5 apps (each have 3-6 models). As a whole, this project is definitely something I would reuse in other projects, but it would only be useful if it included all the apps because they are intrinsically related.

Therefore, I want to package this project to make it reusable following the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/reusable-apps/) and [Django cookiecutter django package](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-djangopackage).  However, these examples show only how to package a single app.

From what I have read there are a few options:

1. Make 5 packages
2. Make one app with 30 models and convert `models.py` into a module
3. Make a package with 5 apps (Similar to how [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) is setup)

I am planning on using option 3 because I think option 1 is overkill and option 2 is considered bad practice (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953057/django-packaging-project-with-multiple-apps) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508412/packaging-a-django-project-with-multiple-apps)).  The issue I see with option 3 is that then a project that uses this package would have to install all 5 apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'project',
    'project.app1',
    'project.app2',...
]
```

Is there a way to avoid having to install all the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` if I package the project with 5 apps? Or is option 1 or 2 better for this use case?

Comment: I'm also trying to do this. any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the apps are very coupled and can only be used together, IMO makes no sense to have them in different packages. So option 3 is the answer: put them all in a single package installable via `setup.py` if it's private, or publish on `pip` if it's public.

Shameless plug: for other advice related to Django apps, you might be interested in my "Your Django app is a User Interface" talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnzvjn1v1CY (slides [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_AYth0Ix0bw3Z2BiEt_Bl_tjYk5cuvLEqGl93djpEtU/edit?usp=sharing))